# How to suppress UI exceptions in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, exception

I am creating design app where users can drag and drop controls to some surface.
Some controls in toolbar can contains broken logic and generate exceptions when injected to the surface.
I would like to suppress some unhandled exception comming from the 3rd party controls when they are dropped.

I want to suppress this UI exception and show some kind of popup:

```
workArea.Dispatcher.UnhandledException += MainContainerDispatcherUnhandledException
```

Is is possible to handle and suppress based on the source of origin?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) and in case you recieve it, identify the  control that made it happen, and

- or show to the user a user-friendly message
- or show some red surface (more or less like VS does)
- or use an Adorner with animaniton (cool, but more to program)

Hope this helps.

Comment: But when control already have exception. How can i leave it on surface? Maybe exceptions will be rised again? How can i suppress exception for one control and show adorner with red message?

Comment: @Evgeny: I mean do not draw a *control* but some surface. Try to make some control crash in VS designer: you will see a white rectangle with a red cross on it in the place where the control *supposed* to be.

Comment: I understand idea. But problem that Dispatcher.UnhandledException and AppDomain.UnhandledException doesnot contains property to determine which control caused exception. Or at least i cannot find it.

Comment: @Evgeny: naturally that should be handled by *your* code. It's not somethign that framework can handle automatically. Define some global var of current control and use it.

Comment: When i load surface created by user it can contains huge amount of controls in same time. And they will be loaded in the same time... And problem to determine controls that throws exceptions. Or at least determine that exceptions appears inside surface and not in my application.

Comment: @Evgeny: you have a some control drawing/validation step I immagine. There you go throw collection of contorls and validate/draw them. So there, in the iteration you can know which *last* control was *before* getting the exception. That *last* control would be actually that one that generates exception.

Comment: Ther is no such step. They are loaded in external libs that cannot be overridden.

Comment: @Evgeny: did you pass them in collection ?

Comment: Could you try to pass them one-by-one, or its performance issue?

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to hadle the event: `e.Handled=true;`. [DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs.Handled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherunhandledexceptioneventargs.handled.aspx). [Unhandled Exception Handler For WPF Applications](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/90866/Unhandled-Exception-Handler-For-WPF-Applications.aspx)