# wpf unhandled exception

Tags: c#, wpf, unhandled-exception

In my WPF application some users get "application generated an exception that can not handle" error. I've implemented [Application.DispatcherUnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception.aspx) event handler but the the exception isn't handled by this event. 
Is there any possibility that exception occurs outside application causing closing my application, maybe something with memory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One thing you could try, in addition to the DispatcherUnhandledException is to listen for exceptions coming from the AppDomain

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += 
        new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
```

This should, in theory, catch all exceptions related to your application and not just ones running within the Dispatcher.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try add also this to your Application Startup?:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience if only some users get the error (and those users get the error all the time), then it is likely that the project file references dll's without setting the 'CopyToLocal' property to true - therefore assuming that all users have the dll's installed in the GAC - which may not be the case for some users.

Answer (score 0):

If your handler is called but exception remains unhandled, it is necessary to handle the event: `e.Handled=true;` see: [How to suppress UI exceptions in wpf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084196/how-to-suppress-ui-exceptions-in-wpf/10085553)

Comment: exception is handled, I think that solution proposed by tomasmcguinness and Dummy01 will solve the problem